# Which functions should I hook to tell me what process renamed a file?

Tags: dll, process, hook, file-monitoring

I want to write a windows hook that can tell me whenever file extensions have been changed, and what process changed them.

The approach I was planning to use is Trampolining https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)

I need 2 pieces of information to be returned to my main program from the injected DLL.
 1. The path of the file that had its extension changed
 2. What Process changed it

i.e. C:/whatever/MyFile.txt became C:/whatever/MyFile.doc 
     and PID 7344, SomeProgram.exe was what changed it

Which function(s) must I reroute to my injected DLL in order to get all of the information I need.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to hook [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557671(v=vs.85).aspx) since this is the "common ground" for most ways to rename a file. You would need to check whether `FileInformationClass` is `FileRenameInformation`.

Getting the PID would be as simple as calling `GetCurrentProcessId()` because your DLL would be running inside the process which is renaming the file anyway.

However, there are still other ways how to "rename" a file, such as by copying the file (either using a WinAPI function to copy files or by actually opening the new file and writing its content) and then deleting the original. This would not be caught by this hook because it's technically no rename operation. Another, more sneaky way would be creating a hardlink to the same file with the new name and then deleting the original one.

Also, you would need to think about having both a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of your DLL, otherwise half of the applications would go below your radar.

But in general, hooking windows APIs, especially in all processes, is strongly discouraged by Microsoft and might also get you into issues with security softwares. Depending on your use case and whether it's just a private tool for a specific problem or a piece of software you want to release to third parties, it might be worth looking into building a driver to accomplish this task, similar to how Process Monitor does it.

Comment: Thank you for a very insightful answer.  I upvoted it but it says I need a 15 reputation to effect the score.  

I have read in a few places that the driver is a better approach.  Most of the stuff I found relating to how the process monitor drivers were set up,  was really old articles from the late 1990's.  

Any idea where I can find an up to date free LGPL driver that works like the one in Process Monitor?  Or at least some more up to date information.